# HTTP client with keep-alive

Tags: c++, sockets, asio

I am trying to implement an HTTP client using `asio` (the standalone version of `boost::asio`) for educational purposes. My problem is with keep-alives (at the HTTP level). If the server still has the socket open, I want to just send data over it. If the server already closed it's end, I need to first call `connect()`. I tried just writing to the socket and if it comes back with an error then reconnecting, but even if the server already closed it's end, the write still comes back fine (i.e. no error), effectively losing data. How can I determine if the connection is still open on the server, or at least if the write really succeeded?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920370/how-to-check-if-a-socket-connection-is-live-in-boostasio

Comment: Off-topic: is your HTTP client project available somewhere? Is it closed or open source?

Comment: I'm not sure I would recommend `asio` for this. I find that it creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @MSalters why do you say so?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: Because I'm maintaining such a HTTP client, and it has multiple comments about workarounds and hacks needed. And I have multiple bugs in the backlog that will require even more hacks.

Comment: @roalz It is here: https://bitbucket.org/BMB/mini-server I am happy to share it, but I don't know how much use it will be.