# Why does tcp::socket::is_open() method return true when connecting a non-existent address?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I connected a non-existent address using tcp::socket::connect method and it returned WSAETIMEDOUT(10060) as expected. But why invoking tcp::socket::is_open() returned 1(true) ? I think it should return 0(false), because of establishing connection failed.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    boost::asio::io_context context;
    tcp::socket socket(context);
    /*non-existent address 111.111.111.111:8080*/
    tcp::endpoint endpoint(address::from_string("111.111.111.111"), 8080);
    error_code result_error;
    socket.connect(endpoint, result_error);

    /* error code: WSAETIMEDOUT [10060]
    *  description: established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
    */
    std::cout << "error code: " << result_error.value()<< result_error.message() << std::endl;

    /*returned 1*/
    std::cout << "is_open returned: "<< socket.is_open() << std::endl;
}
```

I expect the output of is_open to be 0, but the actual output is 1.

Comment: as this boost documentation, the is_open function just check the socket is open.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/is_open.html

Answer (score 0):

The `is_open` function just check if the socket is "open" (the [`open`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/open.html) function have been successfully called), not if the socket is connected.

In short, `is_open` checks socket creation status, not socket connection status.

If you see [this old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9951857/440558) it will tell you that it's impossible to know the connection status, and also gives a workaround (keep the connection status yourself).

Comment: It would have also been prudent to check that `error_code` from `connect`.

Comment: thanks, currently, I close socket every time getting error from invoking connect/read/write methods, which makes is_open equals to is_connected