# Customising socket/close syscalls in boost::asio

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have a library which communicates with TCP and UDP sockets using `boost::asio`. This library is cross-platform and delegates some operations to the application using it via callbacks. In the case of sockets, the following must occur:

1. Library opens a socket (for an outbound connection).
2. Application receives a callback allowing it to customise behaviour
3. Library connects a socket and uses it
4. Application receives a callback allowing it to do any necessary cleanup
5. Library closes the socket

Here's how I thought I can achieve this:

```cpp
class CustomizableTcpSocket {
public:
  template <typename T, typename U>
  auto async_connect(T&& endpoint, U&& handler) {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    socket_.open(endpoint.protocol(), ec);
    native_code_.socket_did_open(socket_.native_handle());
    return socket_.async_connect(std::forward<U>(handler));
  }

  // same for async_write_some as well
  template <typename... Args>
  auto async_read_some(Args&&... args) {
    return socket_.async_read_some(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  ~CustomizableTcpSocket() {
    if (socket_.is_open()) {
      native_code_.socket_will_close(socket_.native_handle());
    }
  }

private:
  NativeCode native_code_;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
};
```

What I'm finding is that asio is sometimes closing the socket (at the OS level) before my destructor fires.

Is there a way I can be notified of a socket closing *before* asio actually does it?

Comment: I would suggest go through the documentation thoroughly.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818665/how-to-check-if-socket-is-closed-in-boost-asio
may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASIO has a debugging feature called [handler tracking](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html).

You could use it to intercept [socket closures](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/f9e4489b576cedc92f85d6db8843138de1f5ada1/asio/include/asio/detail/impl/reactive_socket_service_base.ipp#L103) which are invoked as:

```
  BOOST_ASIO_HANDLER_OPERATION((reactor_.context(), "socket", &impl, impl.socket_, "close"));
```

Just `#define BOOST_ASIO_HANDLER_OPERATION(...)` to whatever function you want called and in there check that arg 5 == `"close"`.

Here's an [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/handler_tracking/custom_tracking.hpp) of how to use handler tracking.

For reference: the actual `close()` operation is [not straightforward](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/a10d3595eb33bb6cb75199533c5178a2b8676332/asio/include/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp#L293). Better to leave that as it is.

Comment: Thank you, so far this appears to be exactly what I need!
Word of warning to anyone else doing this: It changes the class hierarchy of things inside `boost/asio` - define the macro using `-DBOOST_ASIO_CUSTOM_HANDLER_TRACKING="myheader.hpp"` else you'll end up with memory corruption in any place that doesn't have that macro defined before including boost.